# AWS S3 Sync - Billing Reports GetObject (Access Denied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a consolidated billing account from which I am trying to download the Billing Reports using S3 Sync. When I try to do this it throws "Access Denied" errors when syncing the directory.

So the bash command I am running is:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-aws-bills /home/user/Billing
```

The command above logs in with the 123456789:user/IAMUser which is a cross account IAM user.
The S3 Bucket has a policy of:

```
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/IAMUser"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-aws-bills"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/IAMUser"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-aws-bills/*"
    }
```

When I run the bash command it connects ok and I see the files listed but each of the files errors with:

```
download failed: s3://my-aws-bills/123456789-aws-billing-csv-2018-03.csv to ../../home/user/Billing/123456789-aws-billing-csv-2018-03.csv An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

If I upload a file from my desktop to that bucket (having logged in as the account owner) then S3 sync works correctly for that file but not the ones that have been put there by AWS Billing.
I also notice that I do not, through the root user, have access to see the permissions on the csv files that AWS has put there.

I think I am bumping into a permissions issues but I would have thought the permissions I had already applied would have been enough to download these files?

Comment: You mention that you can upload a file to that bucket. However, your S3 bucket policy does not allow you PutObject permissions. This means that you have another policy or ACL involved. Look into the IAM policy assigned to your account and any other ACLs assigned to the bucket.

Comment: I uploaded the file using the account owner, not the user running the sync, which would have uploaded it with the default ACL.
There are no other ACLs on that bucket.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe (though cannot prove) that the problem here was I was trying to use a user that was in a different account going across accounts.
I eventually created another IAM user within the same account as the billing account and could access with the same permissions as above (I just changed out the IAMUser).
It would make sense that you cannot access other people's billing data programmatically across accounts but I have not seen it documented anywhere.